# Python For Loop Query

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working on Python For Loop:-

I am expecting a Output as below

---

Dog
A Dog would make a great pet.

Cat 
A cat would make a great pet.

Parrot
A Parrot would make a great pet.

Any of these animals would make a great pet!

---

By using the below code:-

```
animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Parrot']
for pets in animals:
    print(pets)
    print(pets.title() + "would make a great pet" + ".\n")

    print("Any of these animals would make a great pet!")
    break
```

But i am getting a different output:-

---

Dog
Dogwould make a great pet.

Any of these animals would make a great pet!

---

How can this be rectified?

Comment: Why have you put an unconditional `break` in the loop? Your loop will only run one in that case.

Comment: `str.title()` Only capitalizes the first letter of the word, it won't add `A` in front of it. You have to do that yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're breaking out of your loop after the first one.

Try this:

```
animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Parrot']
for pets in animals:
    print(pets, 'A', pets.title() + "would make a great pet" + ".\n")

print("Any of these animals would make a great pet!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Parrot']
for pets in animals:
    print(pets)
    print(f"{pet.title()} A {pet} would make a great pet.\n")
print("Any of these animals would make a great pet!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not add a whitespace when using + on strings, you have to add it manually. 
Also, you break in the for loop which leads to it stopping after the first animal.
The following code should work:

```
animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Parrot']
for pets in animals:
    print(pets)
    print("A " + pets.title() + " would make a great pet" + ".\n")

print("Any of these animals would make a great pet!")
```